# MYSQL select count of results by month

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having a hard time searching for this answer, please let me know as it seems like something someone must have asked already.

I have a lot of rows in a db that look like this:

```
dest    at(timestamp)
A   2015-07-01
B   2015-07-01
A   2015-07-01
C   2015-07-01
A   2015-07-01
```

I want, for every month from 2015-07-01 until now, a counting of how many rows have which 'dest' so if these were the only rows, I would get:

```
2015-07-01
A 3
B 1
C 1
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. What do I need to do?

Comment: What you want to do is pivoting your table or not? If column `at(timestamp)` has various data, it must  be a very difficult thing. Take a look of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
select dest, at(timestamp), count(*)
from _tablename_
group by dest, at(timestamp)
```

If you are trying to group by months, you can do

```
select dest, month(timestamp), count(*)
from _tablename_
group by dest, month(timestamp)
```

Comment: is it really so simple?!

Comment: Should be. :-) Works for me. Report back if not.